# Linphone Android: missing libraries of the processors?

Tags: android, arm, libs, linphone

i'm getting crazy with this thing...
I've installed all, compiled all, retried a lot of time, followed various guides....
At the end i cam up with the project in eclipse without error (finally).
But... hey! it crash with this logcat!

```
01-13 15:36:26.123: D/dalvikvm(17992): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
01-13 15:36:26.208: D/dalvikvm(17992): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 113K, 13% free 9552K/10951K, paused 19ms, total 20ms
01-13 15:36:26.208: I/dalvikvm-heap(17992): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.295MB for 2908176-byte allocation
01-13 15:36:26.233: D/dalvikvm(17992): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 11% free 12391K/13831K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 21ms
01-13 15:36:26.303: D/dalvikvm(17992): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 12391K/13831K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
01-13 15:36:26.308: I/dalvikvm-heap(17992): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.854MB for 1635856-byte allocation
01-13 15:36:26.333: D/dalvikvm(17992): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 10% free 13988K/15431K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 24ms
01-13 15:36:26.363: I/Linphone(17992):  ==== Phone information dump ====
01-13 15:36:26.363: I/Linphone(17992): DEVICE=GT-I9100
01-13 15:36:26.363: I/Linphone(17992): MODEL=GT-I9100
01-13 15:36:26.363: I/Linphone(17992): SDK=16
01-13 15:36:26.363: I/Linphone(17992): Linphone version is null (2211)
01-13 15:36:26.373: W/Unable to load optional library lib(17992): avutil-linphone-arm
01-13 15:36:26.373: W/Unable to load optional library lib(17992): swscale-linphone-arm
01-13 15:36:26.373: W/Unable to load optional library lib(17992): avcodec-linphone-arm
01-13 15:36:26.378: W/Unable to load optional library lib(17992): crypto-linphone-armeabi-v7a
01-13 15:36:26.378: W/Unable to load optional library lib(17992): ssl-linphone-armeabi-v7a
01-13 15:36:26.378: W/Unable to load optional library lib(17992): srtp-armeabi-v7a
01-13 15:36:26.378: W/Unable to load optional library lib(17992): zrtpcpp-armeabi-v7a
01-13 15:36:26.378: W/dalvikvm(17992): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/linphone/core/LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl;
01-13 15:36:26.378: D/AndroidRuntime(17992): Shutting down VM
01-13 15:36:26.378: W/dalvikvm(17992): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410c42a0)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactory.instance(LinphoneCoreFactory.java:43)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.startLibLinphone(LinphoneManager.java:550)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.createAndStart(LinphoneManager.java:344)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at org.linphone.LinphoneService.onCreate(LinphoneService.java:157)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2414)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load linphone-armeabi-v7a: findLibrary returned null
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.<clinit>(LinphoneCoreFactoryImpl.java:69)
01-13 15:36:26.378: E/AndroidRuntime(17992):    ... 18 more
```

I think the problem is this: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load linphone-armeabi-v7a: findLibrary returned null

But (because i've done all) i don't know why something is missing and where i can take this.
Can someone help me? I really don't know how to do, i have no more idea.
Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to fix this problem? I seem to have exactly the same issue!

Comment: nope.
and the team doesn't respond, and i've lost the customer.

Comment: adding these folders(armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86) to my project libs folder solved this problem. you can use this https://www.linphone.org/snapshots/android/liblinphone-android-sdk-2.3.zip link to download those folders.

Comment: After `make`, there should be a libs/armeabi-v7a/liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this. After many searches and many tries I finally fixed it.

I changed `prepare.py` in this line:

```
Preparator.__init__(self,targets,default_targets=['armv7','arm64','x86','x86_64'], virtual_targets=android_virtual_targets)
```

I resolved it and ran `./prepare.py` again and I found x86 and x86-x64 dirs and *.so files in the lib directory. I can run linphone android app on all android devices.

I hope I helped you to solve your problem.