# Linphone compiling for android error ndk r10e

Tags: android, android-ndk, linphone

I managed to build and import the linphone project (eclipse Indigo Openjava 7  ubuntu 12.04  ndk 10re android sdk 19)

I followed this guide :  http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html#.VXmhVc9Viko

Now I got a runtime error telling can not find the armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86

I imported from https://www.linphone.org/snapshots/android/liblinphone-android-sdk-2.3.zip into the  project .  Same error

I need to know under what NDK and Android SDK versions the armeabi-v7a will run properly?

This link is the same problem
[Linphone Android: missing libraries of the processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096183/linphone-android-missing-libraries-of-the-processors)

Comment: Just follow the steps given on coders hub blog(your mentioned link). All steps are very clear and easy to setup Linphone android.